# Use SQL Server database for code first migrations in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations, sql-server-2012-express

I have been going around and around trying to use a SQL Server Database with code first migrations. For my latest attempt I:

- created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application project (yes, I want to use this template)
- created the model entities
- created the data context class that inherits from dbcontext
- Placed the following connection string in the Web.config residing in the application root:

  ```
   add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=DatingAnAsianWoman;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient"
  ```
- In the Package Manager I input:

  ```
  Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName UsersContext
  ```
- Followed by:

  ```
  Update-Database
  ```

At this point I am receiving the following error:

```
The connection string 'DefaultConnection' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."
```

I would appreciate any help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ack! I didn't even realize providerName was to be specified as a separate key value!